# How to activate onclicklistener from Voice action - Android

Tags: java, onclicklistener, actionlistener, voice-recognition, android-studio-3.0

I would like some help with this theme. I'm developing an app that requires voice actions. I'm using Cardvied, RecyclerView and ViewHolder. Right now, the app only have touch actions, it list some information, and you can enter in details if you click on the ítems. I would like to do is that this click become a voice action. Of course, the app will execute some voice actions like "Open ítem 1" or "close ítem". I would appreciate your help guys!! even if it's not possible or if I have to make some research, everything is welcome. Have a nice week.

Comment: not, you can't "click" a button with your voice

Comment: @Stultuske, but is there a way to activate some actions with voice?? I have tried some, but microphone must be on always, and that consumes a lot of energy from the device.